# How do I get Firebase on an iOS Swift app to code sign properly in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Currently, I have an iOS app I'm building using Swift/SwiftUI and using Firebase as the backend for my efforts. I can run this app locally in the simulator but when I go to install using automatic code signing in Xcode (I have an Apple Developer account I pay for) I am then presented with an error (show below explanation).

I figured I would try to test deploying to my phone with a basic Swift/SwiftUI app with no dependencies added, and I was able to get it to work just fine. I then took the same code and added in Firebase and ran the configuration initializer in the entry file and when I try to push to my phone I get the same error I mentioned before).

You will see that I'm using Xcode 14 in the error below but I'm also receiving this error in Xcode 13.

At this point it has to do with Firebase, I just can't seem to see anything to allow me to properly build and deploy.

```
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-06-09 20:25:58 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001121282f0 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 264
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011215c3f8 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000107165ab8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011215c17c -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1196
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011392184c __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2328
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000107272968 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001072733d4 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001bbbca5f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001bbbcc1b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001bbbd38a8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001bbbd4404 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001bbbdec98 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001bbd8c360 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001bbd8b080 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 8228;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 14.0 (21257.0.0.0.22) (Build 14A5228q)
Timestamp: 2022-06-09T15:25:58-05:00
```

Comment: How does that error relate to firebase? It looks like it is a device kit issue.

Comment: @loremipsum This only happens after adding Firebase. I’m not sure what else could be triggering this issue. If I have no frameworks in a basic Hello World app it deploys just fine, and the second I add Firebase and initialize it then it won’t deploy.

Comment: Maybe use an older version or switch to SPM instead of CocoaPods or vice versa.

Comment: @loremipsum I'm using SPM and tried using CocoaPods just now and unfortunately they have install issues on M1 systems from the install errors I got. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I am using CocoaPods on M1 and not having any issues. Perhaps you have an older version or your Podfile was not properly configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out that it was a Firebase Package called "FirebaseAnalyticsOnDeviceConversionWrapper" that was preventing this installation. I noticed when I built the app and tried manually copying it that it was showing that during install and failed after showing it. I removed this from the list of dependencies and it built.

Comment: I am happy you solved the issue but this answer doesn't tell us what you did - only that you saw a Package. What did you do to correct the issue specifically? That would be good info for future readers that also encounter the issue.

Comment: @Jay I had this "FirebaseAnalyticsOnDeviceConversionWrapper" added into the project dependencies, which I just copied everything from the Firebase package dependencies. Apparently this causes some issues...not too sure but I saw this trying to install when I manually tried doing a build and installing the app and it failed on it. Once I removed that from trying to install with the app then it installed to my device perfectly. I modified my answer above hopefully to reflect that.