# SPM firebase-ios-sdk - "Unable to Install

Tags: firebase, swift-package-manager

i wanna use the firebase-ios-sdk through SPM. The integration works fine. As i wanna install the app on my real device, i get the following error. When running it on simulator, it works fine.

```
Unable to install "AppName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-06-17 13:19:08 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
```

Same issues in the internet got resolved by changing to "Embed and sign" in the targets options. Sadly i can´t change these settings.

[image: target_settings]

Comment: You may need to update the Xcode version. See potential duplicate at The code signature version is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the actual version of Xcode:
Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer of the same problem worked for me as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566375/how-do-i-get-firebase-on-an-ios-swift-app-to-code-sign-properly-in-xcode)

Long story short, the Firebase SPM Package `FirebaseAnalyticsOnDeviceConversionWrapper` causes issues. There doesn't look  to be an open issue. This was going to be gold plating for me so I just removed it for now and will open an issue with them soon.